# Is there a way to send an extra data with $('#id').uploadifive('upload');

Tags: javascript, ajax, uploadify

I'm trying to send extra data when I'm doing upload. The reason of that is because I need to add some photos to an object, that doesn't exist on that stage. first I have to add that object to my db to get an id and then to call somehow a js function which has to get that id and then to do upload.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to just put the data you want to send along with the request into the URL as a query parameter as a key-value pair.  i.e. http://myurl.com/postIt.php?data=3400

**Update:**
See the uploadify documentation for the [onUploadSuccess event](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/) and then inside that event you will have the information you need to submit the second ajax request that completes your two-part process.

**Note:**
I removed the jQuery Deferred documentation reference as it is likely not needed given the events that are available in the uploadify API.

Comment: I can't do that, because I'm loading all photos which have to be uploaded on the first stage, they are loaded in the uploadifive queue, so I've got a button to send my form when I press that button first I check for any empty fields,(this is ajax send) if all is ok, the object is added, this add gives my id. Then I got the response and call another js function which has this id and call this method $('#id').uploadifive('upload'); here I need to send my id so I can have it when do upload and in the same time to add my photos to a db.